# Sharing query params with named router outlets

Tags: angular

I have a few [named router outlets](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/) in an angular app:

```
<router-outlet name="song"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="songDetails"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="songLyrics"></router-outlet>
```

each of these panes displays information about the song... the player, the metadata, and the lyrics. Is there a way to use the "song id" (from my database) for all three of these without having to have a route like this:

```
/music/(song:1234//songDetails:1234//songLyrics:1234)
```

The "issue" is repeating the id between all three routes. Can I share this and still access it from all the controllers?

Comment: Have you considered creating a shared service for these auxiliary routes ?

Comment: Create a service that pulls the param for the song, looks up the data. Then share the data between all controllers.

Comment: Also consider putting all song details in one outlet, for example in a `SongDetailsComponent`, and in that component's template having the different sections be their own children components.

Comment: shared service is the way to go here @Jeff. take look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) for more info

Comment: Thanks. A service occurred to me, but I was wondering if there was another way. I'll probably go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Shared Service is the way to go. Having a simple service cache the current id and imported by the component modules takes care of this.

```
CachedSongService {
  currentId;
}
```

You can even make getters and setters to protect the ID from being overwritten by specific components.